# android app crashes

Tags: android, android-intent, crash, android-manifest

My app does open the splash and also the background music plays .. but after that it was supposed to open a List Activity but it crashes
i have tried to run the same program before with other names of almost everything but when i retyped the program it crashed.. i have cleaned and refreshed which even doesn't make any difference

My java file

Splash.java:

```
package com.alpha.beta;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Splash extends Activity {
MediaPlayer ourSong;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle beta) {
    super.onCreate(beta);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    ourSong = MediaPlayer.create(Splash.this, R.raw.splash_sound);
    ourSong.start();
    Thread timer = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try {
                sleep(5100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                Intent openStartingPoint = new Intent("com.alpha.beta.MENU");
                startActivity(openStartingPoint);
            }
        }
    };
    timer.start();
}

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        ourSong.release();
        finish();
}
}
```

Manifest File:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.alpha.beta"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Splash"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_app" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Menu"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_app" >
        <action android:name="com.alpha.beta.MENU" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".App"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_app" >
        <action android:name="com.alpha.beta.APP" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </activity>
</application>
```

```
           11-19 18:35:42.291: W/dalvikvm(882): threadid=7: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
           11-19 18:35:42.321: E/AndroidRuntime(882): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-8
           11-19 18:35:42.321: E/AndroidRuntime(882): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.alpha.beta.Menu }
           11-19 18:35:42.321: E/AndroidRuntime(882):   at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1408)
           11-19 18:35:42.321: E/AndroidRuntime(882):   at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1378)
           11-19 18:35:42.321: E/AndroidRuntime(882):   at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2817)
           11-19 18:35:42.321: E/AndroidRuntime(882):   at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2923)
           11-19 18:35:42.321: E/AndroidRuntime(882):   at com.alpha.beta.Splash$1.run(Splash.java:26)
           11-19 18:35:46.190: I/Process(882): Sending signal. PID: 882 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way

```
  Intent openStartingPoint = new Intent(Splash.this,Menu.class);
  startActivity(openStartingPoint);
```

**Edit** :- Some time it is the issue of not get the context of that activity.That's why you may get exception as `ActivityNotFoundException`.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought. In the intent, you have specified class name as **MENU**, but in manifest, it is *Menu*. try changing it, case sensitivity might be a problem. Also define the action for your **Menu** class. Action name should be **VIEW**.

Does both the Activities(Splash and Menu) belongs to same package, if yes
then try

```
    Intent i = new Intent(Splash.this, Menu.class);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

startActivity(i);
```

Comment: yes they belong to same package....approximately this'll also do .. sorry but i have found the easier way... this seems like you are very good in this ... thanx